OS X diff3 using process substitution returns "diff3: logic error"
Consider this trivial example.
OS version:
$ sw_vers
ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     15.1.1
BuildVersion:       24B91

diff3 version:
$ diff3 --version
FreeBSD diff3 20220517

Using files:
$ diff3 /etc/hosts /etc/hosts /etc/hosts

Using process substitution:
$ diff3 <(cat /etc/hosts) <(cat /etc/hosts) <(cat /etc/hosts)
====1
1:1,9c
diff3: logic error

If you run it again, you can get different output:
$ diff3 <(cat /etc/hosts) <(cat /etc/hosts) <(cat /etc/hosts)
====2
1:0a
3:0a
2:1,9c
diff3: logic error

